# Call REST WCF-Service creating by C# from PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wcf, web

Please can we help me for this issue:
i m creating a Web service WCF with C# in REST not SOAP with some methode like https://..../ForMobile.svc/getUsersSMI/params, and i want to call this Web service by PHP my methode has one params in input.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define webHttpBinding binding for wcf service to be a restfull wcf service. sample bindings are as

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="AndroidWCF.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- Service Endpoints -->
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
      behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="AndroidWCF.IService1">
        <!--<identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>-->

      </endpoint>

      <!--<endpoint address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
    </service>

  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

you can find complete guide here https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803009/Configure-WCF-Service-to-REST

Comment: Thank you for this clarification for restfull wcf, but i need to consume this RESTfull by a programme PHP client

Comment: once it will be restful you can call it by PHP using curl or similar, it will be similar as other url you can use in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all, this is my code PHP to call REST WCF :

```
   $data = array(
          'query1' => 'parameter1 ', 
          'text' => 'Hi, Message from android example'
   );
   $url = "https://..../Mobile.svc/getParam";
   $ch = curl_init ($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
   application/json'));
   $response = curl_exec ($ch);          
   if(!$response){
           die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
       }
   curl_close($ch);
   echo html_entity_decode($response);
```

this my code PHP it's work but when i have param in my WCF i don't got response, in other information i use postmen for test